# Turning react native maps on/off using switch

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to use switch to turn on/off react native maps so as user can save battery from loading map?

Comment: What do you mean by turning on and off the map?

Comment: Like grabDriver app? where user is able to disable map or enable it. is it a simple hide/show or is there more than just that?